# How to tweet in C#

Tags: c#, twitterizer

So I am very new to C#, I started learning it a few days ago and I would like to know how you can tweet with C#. I have searched google a lot, looked at some YouTube videos, but they are all old. I found Twitterizer.net, which has this code:

```
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
tokens.AccessToken = "XXX";
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "XXX";
tokens.ConsumerKey = "XXX";
tokens.ConsumerSecret = "XXX";

TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, "Hello,         #Twitterizer");
if (tweetResponse.Result == RequestResult.Success)
{
    messagebox.Show("Message Tweeted!");
}
else
{
   messageBox.Show("cannot tweet");
}
```

I put this code in a button, 'button1', but it doesn't seem to work it pops up a messagebox saying cannot tweet. I have no idea why this is happening. I put this at the top using twitterizer;. I also got my consumer key, consumersecret, token and tokensecret. So I don't know what is the problem, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: <ShamelessPlug> I wrote a blog post on this subject one time - http://blog.kitchenpc.com/2011/01/22/rise-of-the-twitterbot/

Comment: out of curiosity what was the value tweetResponse.Result. That might help uncovering the problem. e.g. RateLimited vs. BadRequest

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code. (+1 @ConradFrix)

Comment: I'd like to see the error details and the properties in the tweetResponse. (FYI, I'm the author of Twitterizer.)

Comment: @RickySmith, maybe it is the references I am using. I downloaded twitterizer2.zip, extracted it and now I have a bunch of folders

Async
ClientProfile
Full
...
...etc

From which folder do I use the references from?? I just want to do a simple tweet when the button1 is clicked.

Comment: You probably want the 'Full' or 'ClientProfile' binaries, depending on your application's build target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Twitter Callback. Set that up in the Developer section of Twitter.

#### Try the following

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using TweetSharp;
using Hammock.Authentication.OAuth;

public static string Token = "XXX"
public static string TokenSecret = "XXX"
public static string ConsumerKey = "XXX"
public static string ConsumerSecret = "XXX"
public static string Callback = "XXX"

private static TwitterClientInfo TwitterClientInfo = new TwitterClientInfo()
{
    ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey,
    ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret,
};

private static TwitterService TwitterService = new TwitterService(TwitterClientInfo);

public static bool SetUpTwitter()
{
    var OAuthCredentials = new OAuthCredentials
    {
        Type = OAuthType.RequestToken,
        SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
        ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret,
        CallbackUrl = "",
    };

    OAuthRequestToken requestToken = TwitterService.GetRequestToken(Callback);
    Uri authUrl = TwitterService.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken, Callback);

    Process.Start(authUrl.AbsoluteUri);

    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime endTime = currentTime.AddSeconds(30);
    while (currentTime < endTime)
    {
        currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    OAuthAccessToken accessToken = TwitterService.GetAccessToken(requestToken);
    return SendMessage(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret, "Send Sample Tweet");
}

public static bool SendMessage(string token, string tokenSecret, string message)
{
    Token = token;
    TokenSecret = tokenSecret;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenSecret))
        return SetUpTwitter();

    try
    {
        TwitterService.AuthenticateWith(token, tokenSecret);
        TwitterService.SendTweet(message);

        return true;
    }

    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I got 11 errors and I have no idea how to fix them:


Error 1 'twitter.Form1.TwitterClientInfo' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type' C:\Users\ashley\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\twitter\twitter\Form1.cs 226 16 twitter

Comment: Do I need any dlls for this maybe that is the reason?? Should I add reference to twitterizer.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Reference Hammock.ClientProfile, TweetSharp, and Newtonsoft.Json. They all come with TweetSharp

Comment: Alright I have added those refrences. Now I am getting 5 errors:


Error 1 The type or namespace name 'OAuthCredentials' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\ashley\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ twitter\ twitter\Form1.cs 240 32  twitter

Error 2 The name 'OAuthType' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\ashley\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ twitter\ twitter\Form1.cs 242 16  twitter

Comment: Error 3 The name 'OAuthSignatureMethod' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\ashley\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ twitter\ twitter\Form1.cs 243 27  twitter

Error 4 The name 'OAuthParameterHandling' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\ashley\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ twitter\ twitter\Form1.cs 244 29  twitter

Error 5 The name 'Process' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\ashley\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ twitter\ twitter\Form1.cs 253 5  twitter

Comment: And what are the errors? Make sure everything you get an error you right click on the red squiggly and go to Add Reference and add it

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added the 5 errors above, thanks for your help.

Comment: Alright, I have marked it - Can you give me any suggestions on how to fix those errors at the top?

Comment: Never mind all the errors are gone after I put this: 

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using TweetSharp;
using Hammock.Authentication.OAuth;

now how would I make it tweet. Whenever, I click button1?

Thanks a lot for your great help.

Comment: In the Button Click event handler do this: ClassNameOfMyPastedCode.SetUpTwitter();

Comment: Thanks to you. In button1, I put this code: SetUpTwitter(); it tweeted once, however, when you click it, it opens up the twitter Authorization app page and that's all it does. I don't know how it tweeted once? I have no idea how to do the callback and stuff.

Comment: Eh...I'm sorry but your going to have to learn OO programming and C# before doing this. You have to know the fundamentals first

Comment: Alright, thank your for all the help and sorry to bother you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, assisting you isn't possible, so, instead of giving you an exact answer I'll try to help you find out what the underlying issue is.

Place a breakpoint on the `TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, "Hello, #Twitterizer");` line and debug your application. Step over that line, then inspect the value of `tweetResponse.ErrorMessage`. This should provide you with the raw error message from Twitter, if there is one. If there isn't, look at `tweetResponse.Content`. This property will contain the raw response from Twitter, which may be json, xml, or even html, depending on the issue.

If you submit issues pertaining to Twitterizer, these values will almost always be needed to troubleshoot them.