# Twitter status update failed C# Twitterizer

Tags: c#, twitterizer

Twitter status update failed with Error: 'Could not authenticate with OAuth.' The following is the code I put in button1. How do I fix this error? Thanks

```
        OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
        tokens.AccessToken = "I put my accesstoken";
        tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "I put my tokensecret";
        tokens.ConsumerKey = "I put my consumer key";
        tokens.ConsumerSecret = "I put consumer secret";

        TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, "sample tweet");
        if (tweetResponse.Result == RequestResult.Success)
            MessageBox.Show("Twitter status successfully posted");
        else
            label13.Text = string.Format("Twitter status update failed with Error: '{0}'",
                tweetResponse.ErrorMessage);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tweet in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069302/how-to-tweet-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

This example work for me:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/176201/How-Do-I-MyStatus-Update-Twitter-Twitterizer2-C

Also:

- I create only 1 page names "test.aspx" that make an Update in Twitter
- In https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
  my Callbak url was:   `http://172.0.0.1/auth/twitter/callback`
- To run with F5 its work as: `http://localhost:53303/Test.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

Eather your application is deleted or your made error to write token ,secret and keys ect. recheck these this and goto your application setting and select read write and access direct messages
 here it is
[image]

ALL the Best...